# Bayesian networks: What's wrong with my answer?

Tags: probability, bayesian

Consider The following four random binary variables:

[image]

Given the following Bayesian network:

[image]

With the following conditional probability tables:

[image]

I want to calculate **the probability that the sprinkler was on overnight, given that Tracey’s grass is wet**, meaning I want $\mathbb{P}(S=1\mid T=1)$.

My attempt at this is:

$$\mathbb{P}(S=1\mid T=1)=\frac{\mathbb{P}(T=1\mid S=1)\mathbb{P}(S=1)}{\mathbb{P}(T=1)}=$$
$$\frac{\sum_R\mathbb{P}(T=1\mid R,S=1)\mathbb{P}(S=1)}{\sum_{R,S}\mathbb{P}(T=1\mid R,S)\mathbb{P}(R,S)}=$$
$$\frac{\sum_R\mathbb{P}(T=1\mid R,S=1)\mathbb{P}(S=1)}{\sum_{R,S}\mathbb{P}(T=1\mid R,S)\mathbb{P}(R)\mathbb{P}(S)}$$

And then, numerator is:

$$\mathbb{P}(T=1\mid R=1,S=1)\mathbb{P}(S=1) + \mathbb{P}(T=1\mid R=0,S=1)\mathbb{P}(S=1)=$$
$$1\cdot 0.1+0.9\cdot 0.1=0.19$$

Denominator:
$$\sum_{R,S}\mathbb{P}(T=1\mid R,S)\mathbb{P}(R)\mathbb{P}(S)=$$
$$\mathbb{P}(T=1\mid R=1,S=1)\mathbb{P}(R=1)\mathbb{P}(S=1) +$$
$$\mathbb{P}(T=1\mid R=1,S=0)\mathbb{P}(R=1)\mathbb{P}(S=0) +$$
$$\mathbb{P}(T=1\mid R=0,S=1)\mathbb{P}(R=0)\mathbb{P}(S=1) +$$
$$\mathbb{P}(T=1\mid R=0,S=0)\mathbb{P}(R=0)\mathbb{P}(S=0) =$$
$$1\cdot 0.2\cdot 0.1+1\cdot 0.2\cdot 0.9+0.9\cdot 0.8\cdot 0.1+0\cdot 0.8\cdot 0.9=0.272$$

And overall I get: $\frac{0.19}{0.272}=0.698...$

But the book has a completely different answer... 
It is not just the final result that is different, but also their work is confusing to me:
[image]

How did the go from 3.2.13 to 3.2.14, and more importantly, what's wrong with my answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your working of the problem, you correctly write the denominator of your result as

$$\begin{align}
\sum_{R,S}\mathbb{P}(T=&1\mid R,S)\mathbb{P}(R)\mathbb{P}(S) = \\
&\mathbb{P}(T=1\mid R=1,S=1)\mathbb{P}(R=1)\mathbb{P}(S=1) + \\
&\mathbb{P}(T=1\mid R=1,S=0)\mathbb{P}(R=1)\mathbb{P}(S=0) + \\
&\mathbb{P}(T=1\mid R=0,S=1)\mathbb{P}(R=0)\mathbb{P}(S=1) + \\
&\mathbb{P}(T=1\mid R=0,S=0)\mathbb{P}(R=0)\mathbb{P}(S=0)
\end{align}$$

But in your numerator, you forgot to account for the fact that the probability
is conditioned on $R=1$; you need the factor $\mathbb{P}(R=1)$
or  $\mathbb{P}(R=0)$ in the
calculation of the numerator just like you did in the denominator.
The numerator is simply the two terms of the denominator that belong to the event $S=1$:

$$\begin{align}
&\mathbb{P}(T=1\mid R=1,S=1)\mathbb{P}(R=1)\mathbb{P}(S=1) + \\
&\mathbb{P}(T=1\mid R=0,S=1)\mathbb{P}(R=0)\mathbb{P}(S=1) 
\end{align}$$

The calculation from the book is for the probability that Tony's sprinkler was on,
given that Tony's grass is wet *and* Jack's grass is wet.
It seems to me that the step from 3.2.13 to 3.2.14
assumes that $J$ and $T$ are conditionally independent given $R,S$.
I have not yet been able to convince myself that this assumption is true.

Comment: Ohh... Great, Thanks!